# Why CSS Radial Gradient doesn't work well with <!DOCTYPE html> html5

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to add css radial gradient as background to my webpage, when I add html5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>` the radial background becomes (landscape) stripe. Is there wrong with my css radial-gradient code why it is not working well with HTML5

Output:

**with html5 doctype** `<!DOCTYPE html>`

[image]

**Without html5 doctype** 
[image]

My code (no html5 doctype):

**HTML**

```
<!-- <!DOCTYPE html> --> 
<!-- header -->
<body>

<div class="content"></div>

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
    body {
    background: rgba(32,61,227,1);
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(32,61,227,1) 0%, rgba(10,38,69,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(32,61,227,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(10,38,69,1)));
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(32,61,227,1) 0%, rgba(10,38,69,1) 100%);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(32,61,227,1) 0%, rgba(10,38,69,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(32,61,227,1) 0%, rgba(10,38,69,1) 100%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(32,61,227,1) 0%, rgba(10,38,69,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#203de3', endColorstr='#0a2645', GradientType=1 );
    }
```

Comment: With which browsers have you found this issue?

Comment: works fine in latest chrome release, http://tinypic.com/r/2rw7uh1/8

Comment: @EasyBB, why don't you try creating an HTML file on your local machine and then experiment instead of applying CSS to SO's HTML?

Comment: Yeah realized after that. I have a stock CSS that is added to every new HTML doc. Then thought well maybe I should eliminate everything looky there same results lol. Sorry man

Comment: I tried using chrome & firefox developer edition both not working well. @EasyBB

Comment: AlexNewbie look at @Sidsec9 answer and it will work.

Comment: yes it works. nice. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` seems to minimize the height of `html` and `body` to `0%`

Try adding this to your **CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

This will solve your issue

Comment: how would you know this?

Comment: Did you even try my code before down voting?
See it yourself in your developer tools

Comment: No, because I've tried the OP's code and it works fine without what you have. Of course the OP didn't give much to work with either.

Comment: Just because it worked for you does't mean it'll work for everybody else.
My browser had the same problem as the OP.

Comment: Ok specify which browser, which version, etc. instead of a simple answer that doesn't give much thought, reason, or why.

Comment: Chrome version  44.0.2403.125 m

Comment: Version 44.0.2403.107 m is what I have. works fine which is strange. Let me look at something... Alright had to restart now we're on the same level. And then looking further on a new html document I was getting the same results. I usual don't use a blank like that but yes what you wrote works. Sorry mate